# Dock Titanium Desktop Application to the Right

Tags: javascript, desktop-application, alignment, titanium

I have decided to switch from Adobe Air to Titanium Desktop for building applications. Their is no argument why I have :)

Ok, to my issue. I need to align my application to the right side of the monitor on launch. The problem is, everyone has different screen resolutions so there is no way of setting the X and Y coordinates at the start. So what I need to do is find out the screen size of the person's screen and minus the app's width. That way I can provide an X coordinate via Javascript upon the application opening.

Does anyone have any idea at all how I can do that?